# Update statement from laravel does not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two buttons: 1 - insert data in data base, 2 - update the first row... I'm trying to update the first row from database and the function is not working.

my buttons:

```
<form action="{{action('CashierController@openCashier')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px">Iniciar Caixa</button>
</form>

<form action="{{action('CashierController@closeCashier')}}" method="put">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-top: 10px">Fechar Caixa</button>
</form>
```

My BD:

[image]

CashierController:

```
 public function openCashier(){

    $date = date('d-m-Y H:i');
    $status = 1;

    DB::table('cashier')->insert([
        'start' => DB::raw('INET_ATON(\''.$date.'\')'),
        'status' => DB::raw('INET_ATON(\''.$status.'\')'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->to('admin/cashier')
        ->with('date', $date)
        ->with('status', $status);

}

public function closeCashier(){

    $date = date('d-m-Y H:i');
    $status = 0;

    DB::table('cashier')->orderBy('id','desc')->first()
        ->update(array('status'=>$status, 'last'=>$date));

    return redirect()->to('admin/cashier')
    ->with('date', $date)
    ->with('status', $status);
}
```

Routes:

```
//================================Cashier=================================//
Route::get('/admin/cashier', 'CashierController@index');
Route::post('/admin/cashier', 'CashierController@openCashier');
Route::put('/admin/cashier', 'CashierController@closeCashier');
```

there is something wrong in my code? I can't see it

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is there any error message? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Was not showing any error messasge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#form-method-spoofing):

> HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when
>   defining PUT, PATCH or  DELETE routes that are called from an HTML
>   form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form. The
>   value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP request
>   method:

The update is actually using `PUT`. You need to spoof that method in your form.

```
<form action="{{action('CashierController@closeCashier')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-top: 10px">Fechar Caixa</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Rigth... Now it is ok. I'm really thankful ! I also changed DB::table('cashier')->orderBy('id','desc')->first()->update(array('status'=>$status, 'last'=>$date));
replaced first() to where()